# How to access string from one method in another

Tags: java, string, methods

I have a method getMyName and want to access the String myName outside the method.

```java
public String getMyName() {
    setTestStart("Returning name");
    String myName = getActiveName().getMyName();
    setTestInfo("My name is: " + myName);
    setTestEnd();
    return myName;
}
```

I want to get a String myName result and use that result in other methods without constantly calling the whole getMyName method. How can i do that? Sorry for this silly question, I am new in Java.

Comment: you can't. that's the whole reason you call that method, to get that String

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Currently you are returning `myName` so you can assign this return value outside your method. If you want the current active name, you may be able to call `getActiveName().getMyName()` outside depending on the visibility of the methods.

Comment: You can store it in a class variable and initalize this variable in the constructor, than all other methods have the same result. but if the result of `getActiveName().getMyName()` changes this class variable will have a different value, then the method.

Answer (score 0):

you could put your var out of the all method scopes

```java
public class Test{
    private String myName; // it's out of all scopes and will can catch in all methods

    public void getMyName(){
        setTestStart("Returning name");
        myName = getActiveName().getMyName(); // setting value
    }

    public void testMyNameInOtherMethod(){
        setTestInfo("My name is: " + myName); // reading value. so important treating non-declaring and null values
        setTestEnd();
    }

    // others methods...
}
```

you can use contructors to set values when init instances of new class as well